# Which quasiparticles follow which statistics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-spin, spin-statistics, anyons, quasiparticles

*Let me say beforehand that I know this is an ill-defined question, but I believe it is useful anyway.*

For these common quasiparticles:

- Phonons
- Holes
- Plasmons
- Excitons
- Plasmon-polaritons

What statistics do they follow, and under which assumptions? What would be a general way to determine the statistics for a given quasi-particle?

Comment: This seems like a list-based question

Comment: This edit seems to invalidate the posted answer.

Comment: I sincerely don't know how to make it less broad and not invalidate the posted answer. I knew from the beginning this was too broad, this was precisely the intention.

Comment: Which leads me to: if you knew it was too broad & would likely be closed as such, why ask it?

Comment: As I said in the original edit, I believe it is interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if we look at particle as classical ones or quantum ones. In the first case, particles are usually following a **Boltzmann statistics**. However, things become more interesting when entering the quantum world. Here, the spin of the particles become crucial. We have that particles with *integer* spin follow a **Bose-Einstein statistics**. Whereas particles with *half-integer* spin follow a **Fermi-Dirac statistics**. The same is also true if we look at quasi-particle, also in this case we can clearly assign a label for the type of spin. The role of statistic in the quantum world is associated with the exchange of two particles. For Bosons, nothing is changed to the wave-function after the exchange whereas for Fermions the wave-function is multiplied by a minus sign.

An important generalization of the concept of quantum statistic was obtained with the discovery of the fractional quantum Hall effect. Under the action of a strong magnetic field, the quasi particles composed by electrons and flux quanta of the magnetic field, also called **composite fermions**, can acquire a statistic that is not a Bose-like or a Fermi-like. In this case we speak about **anyons**. Under the exchange of two anyons the wave-function can be multiplied by a complex number. This is very interesting because it paves the way to *braiding* these particles in order to perform operations that leads to quantum computing.

A lot of effort is done nowadays because Majorana quasi-particles have an anyonic statistic. Therefore their manipulation could lead to the so called *topological quantum computation*.